# including XML file in another XML file + XML schema validation

Tags: xml, xsd, doctype

I have four three xml files and one xsd file.
This is file videodes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE videodes [
<!ENTITY dvds   SYSTEM "./dvds.xml">
<!ENTITY movies SYSTEM "./movies.xml">
]>
<videodes xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="src/videodes.xsd" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  &dvds;
  &movies;
</videodes>
```

This is file dvds.xml (in the same directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<dvds>
    <dvd id="1">
        <title>The lord of the rings</title>
        <type>Original</type>
        <content>
            <movie movie_id="1"/>
            <movie movie_id="2"/>
            <movie movie_id="3"/>
        </content>
    </dvd>

    <dvd id="2">
        <title>Inception</title>
        <type>Original</type>
        <content>
            <movie movie_id="3"/>
        </content>
    </dvd>
</dvds>
```

And this is file movies.xml (also in the same directory):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<movies>
    <movie id="1">
        <name>Inception</name>
        <director>Christopher Nolan</director>
        <year>2010</year>
        <country>USA</country>
        <actors>
            <actor>Ellen Page</actor>
        </actors>
        <genres>
            <genre>Thriller</genre>
        </genres>
    </movie>

    <movie id="2">
        <name>Two towers</name>
        <director>Peter Jackson</director>
        <year>2003</year>
        <country>USA</country>
        <actors>
        </actors>
        <genres>
            <genre>Action</genre>
            <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        </genres>
    </movie>

    <movie id="3">
        <name>Return of the king</name>
    </movie>
</movies>
```

You can see that I wrote an XML schema for the "main" file (videodes.xml). I think the schema is not important so I'm not posting it here. The thing is that when I put dvds.xml and movies.xml in videodes.xml, it is valid (at least that's what NetBeans is saying). But I want to have dvds and movies stored separately (not in the same file). So I created dvds.xml and movies.xml and included them in videodes.xml. But when I valid the videodes.xml file now, netbeans says it is not valid file. It looks like the files declared in doctype aren't even being included in videodes.xml.

What am I doing wrong ? Am I including it wrong ? Did I declare the doctype wrong ?

Thanks for any answers in advance. And sorry for any grammar mistakes in my English.

Comment: You are declaring the entities and referencing them correctly. This might be a netbeans issue? Try using an absolute path to your dvds/movies XML files. Maybe try removing the `<?xml...` declarations from them too (it shouldn't make a difference though).

Comment: @DevNull Yes, it is probably a netbeans issue. I tried to validate it with DOM and the file is valid even though netbeans says it isn't. Thanks, I wouldn't realize that.